# How to import variable from function in different module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried doing this in the module *choice.py*:

```
def ch():  
    var = int(input("Choose the Operation: \n1 = Binary \n2 = Decimal\n"))  
ch()
```

This is in a different module:

```
from choice import ch
print(var)
```

But it can't find var. What should I do to solve this problem?
The output is supposed to be:

Choose the Operation:
1=Binary
2=Decimal

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide more details. Is `var` inside a function `ch` that is inside a module `choice`? Please be more clear.

Comment: i have edited my question so please find help me out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you want to return the choice value of the input dialog

```
def choose():
    choice = int(input("Choose the Operation: \n1 = Binary \n2 = Decimal\n"))
    return choice
```

and in the main file

```
from choice import choose

print(choose())
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.